# What is this black bar in the Dopesheet and is it the reason I can't play my animation?

Tags: animation, interface, dopesheet

I cant play my animation. There is a black thick bar in the dope sheet and timeline. I think this is the reason. How do I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Added file! go check Myfile (go to google drive)

Comment: it needs an authorization  ;)

Comment: Why not use the file sharing link that moonboots kindly provided? It was made available to users of this community for exactly this purpose. And it always works.

Comment: i see that now.

Comment: i think this is about preview range.

First 
Auto-Set Preview Range
next
Clear Preview Range
then I cant play animation.

i tried in Load Factory Setting.
it not necessarily the Preview Range to play animation.

What is this?

Answer (score 0):

You set **Start** and **End** Frame of your Animation to the same Frame. This means it plays your Animation, but because it is only one frame long, it loops over the same frame. The black Bar is your Animation Range, 1 Frame long. Therefore it is shrunk to a line.

[image]

1. Current Playhead Positiion
2. Start of the Animation (set it to 0 in this case)
3. End of the Animation (set it to 450)

Comment: Is it Timeline?
move cursor to 0 frame>Playback>Set Start Frame
or
last frame>Playback>Set End Frame
Am i correct?

or other?